# Store mysqli_result object (serialize) to achieve caching

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a proper way to store the result returned by mysqli?

My Database class is fairly simple:

```
class Database extends mysqli {

    private function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( 'host', 'user', 'xxxxx', 'database_name' );
        $this->set_charset("utf8");
        $this->query_execute("SET time_zone = '-0:00'");
    }

    public function query( $sql ) {
        $result = parent::query( $sql );

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I want to serialize the `$result` set if let's say the query is the same and store it in a file to achieve basic caching for big queries that take a long time to process. 
The $result will return a "mysqli_result object" and later to retrieve data `$result->fetch_array()` or `$result->fetch_object()` will be used.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `"$result->fetch_object() will be used"` - what for? I mean, PHP has a lot more useful operators to iterate over data. Foreach() for example

Comment: It will be used in a loop while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) { .... } or while ($obj = $result->fetch_array()) { .... }, these methods are native, this question is more for caching, data iteration can always be addressed later, I have no issues with it.

Comment: What do you mean - "native"? Native for what?

Comment: By native I meant using the mysqli fetch_object http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php that will return the current row of a result set as an object

Comment: You've got to deal with *cache*, not mysql. So, you need a native method for cache. In your application you need an *object*, not a mysql method to create it. So, cache an object already.

Comment: Anyway, such file caches seldom being useful. It is often being way more useful to optimize the "big query" to make it fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a proper way to store the result returned by mysqli?

No.
There is no way to cache the result object returned by mysqli.